# User-Agent для заголовка HTTP

Tags: http, java

Привет! Не могли бы вы подсказать, как назначить `User-Agent`, для заголовка `HTTP`. Если будет примерчик, огромное спасибо. Мне просто надо, чтобы, когда мой небольшой робот посещал сайт, он там как-нибудь "Светился". Может статья есть с примерами кода?

Вот код моего небольшого краулера:

**UPD**

```
package crawler;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class crawler {

    /**
     * @author ivan
     * @version 2.2
     * @param args
     */
    private static final String CRAWLER_SOURSE = "C:\\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\\webapps\\wasks\\WEB-INF\\indexer\\urllist.txt";
    private static final String CRAWLER_WRITE = "C:\\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\\webapps\\wasks\\WEB-INF\\indexer\\urllist.txt";
    private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://(.+?.ru)/");
    private static final Set<String> urls = new HashSet<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        Scanner scanner = null;
        URL url = null;

        FileWriter wr = null;
        String sRead = null;

        File file = new File(CRAWLER_SOURSE);

        try {

            scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {

                urls.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            scanner.close();

            for (String s : urls) {
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                try {

                    try {
                        url = new URL(s);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            url.openStream()));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }
                while (true) {

                    sRead = reader.readLine();
                    if (sRead == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    buffer.append(sRead);
                }

                Matcher m = p.matcher(buffer.toString());

                while (m.find()) {
                    url = new URL(m.group());
                    String group = new String(m.group());
                    urls.add(group);
                    System.out.println(urls);
                }
            }

            wr = new FileWriter(CRAWLER_WRITE);
            for (String s : urls) {
                wr.write(s + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (wr != null) {
                try {
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Как видно он сохраняет страницы. Было бы неплохо, если бы веб мастер знал, что я обошел его сайт. Плюс хочется дать имя краулера, как у дядек крупных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

См. [класс HTTPRequest](http://www.agentkernel.com/javadocs/com/cometway/net/HTTPRequest.html)

Comment: А можно простой примерчик,какой-нибудь,для лучшего усвоения,спасибо)
Вот:

Comment: Покажите весь код, и я подскажу как в него вставить UA. BTW, совершенно не обязательно использовать HTTP-классы, можно и сокеты:

http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/java_http_web/article04.html

Comment: Все добавил)